# Will the 20GB space be available for free after the expiration of 6-months valid music track?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I read a new offer from ubutuone music store. That is, when you buy a new music track from ubuntuone music store, you will get 20GB cloud space. My doubt is related with 20GB of disk space.  Will the 20GB space be available for free after the expiration of 6-months valid music track, unless i am renewing the music store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you would need to get enough referrals to get the 20GB for free, or pay for more storage, or renew your streaming plan. The 20GB you get with the music streaming is included in that plan, and not a free-for-forever addition to your account separate from the streaming, when you purchase the plan.

Answer (score 0):

This promotion seems a bit misleading... but looks like after the 6 months both the music streaming service and the storage expire.

You can read more on their FAQ:

[What is the free Music Streaming promotion?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-is-the-free-music-streaming-promotion/)

[What happens when my free six month Music Streaming subscription expires?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-happens-when-my-free-six-month-music-streaming-subscription-expires/)

Answer (score 0):

I just purchased one single track and I have 6 months of 20mb cloud storage and mobile streaming access. So the promotion stands by its word. I'm using Ubuntu desktop to sync files and use the Android Ubuntu One Music app. If you use the Android app, be sure to switch from the default "Demo" setting to your Ubuntu One Cloud. The user interface for this app needs some work.